# Returning a DateTimeField results in OperationError

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class TheDate(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    theDate = models.DateTimeField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """returns a string representation of the model"""
        return self.theDate
```

Even trying to access the values store or trying to save a new field results in the following traceback:

```
OperationalError at /admin/meal_plans/thedate/
no such table: meal_plans_thedate
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/meal_plans/thedate/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: meal_plans_thedate
Exception Location: C:\Users\$$$\Desktop\meal_planner\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 383
Python Executable:  C:\Users\$$$\Desktop\meal_planner\ll_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\$$$\\Desktop\\meal_planner',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\$$$\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0',
 'C:\\Users\\$$$\\Desktop\\meal_planner\\ll_env',
 'C:\\Users\\$$$\\Desktop\\meal_planner\\ll_env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 28 Jun 2020 13:18:06 +0000
```

Comment: The error is saying the relevant table doesn't exist in your database. Have you ran the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands?

Comment: You should migrate your models, futhermore you should return a string, so call `str` on the `theDate`.

Answer (score 2):

The error means you did not properly migrate the models. You need to run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` to migrate the database such that it creates tables at the database side.

Furthermore `__str__` is supposed to return a `str`ing object, you can for example call `str(…)` on the `self.theDate`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class TheDate(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    theDate = models.DateTimeField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """returns a string representation of the model"""
        return str(self.theDate)
```